# Record Minecraft with recordmydesktop on Linux Mint 12 64bit

Tags: video, recording

With Ubuntu 11.04 or 11.10 I was able to record Minecraft video with the following command:

```
recordmydesktop --windowid $(xdotool selectwindow) --no-cursor --full-shots --fps 25 --no-wm-check --no-frame -o ~/out.ogv
```

After installing Linux Mint 12, this fails in several ways:

- Most of the time the recording area doesn't align with the application window I just clicked - Maybe the geometry is not reported correctly (I'm using Compiz on a dual-screen desktop)
- When the area aligns the recording dimensions are not quite correct - It looks like the area of the frame is still included.
- When the Minecraft window is even within the frame, no motion can be seen in the resulting video. Video is still recorded, because if I remove `--no-cursor` I can see it moving around.
- Sometimes it seems like it completely ignores the Minecraft window and records whatever is behind it.
- VLC and MPlayer seem to have trouble playing the resulting file, while Totem works.

Any idea of a **fix**? If not, has anybody been able to **record Minecraft videos on Linux Mint 12 64bit**?